# How to write single binary code to output pin

Tags: programming, atmega

I am relatively new to arduino and coding in general and im just looking for a code to write a single string of binary code e.g.; "01000111101"
To a specified output pin instead of copying and pasting

"Digital write (high)
Digital write (low)
Etc."

preferably with the option to change speed between bits.
Would be very appreciative for someone to help me out

Comment: look at example LED blink code for outputting single bit of data ... look at arrays for indexed list of data ... also at `for` loops for generating an index value

Comment: your question is a general programming question ... it is not Arduino specific, so it does not belong here

Comment: It would be easy enough to make this Arduino specific @Arbadatduino if you specified a specific Arduino board and pin.  So edit your TITLE and QUESTION.

Answer (score 2):

If timing is not critical, consider dividing the number of interest by 2. If there was a remainder set the Arduino pin to 1. If not set it to 0. Then delay for as long as needed. Keep doing this until there is nothing left to divide 2 into.

However, sending out data in serial fashion is as old as computers. Likely older. Consequently there are a lot of built in features which do this.  Specifically, it is not necessary to explicitly code up a function to convert a value to serial data. Even on an Arduino.